# getEditResponseURL() to string to email gets 404 error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have code that produces the correct & identical edit response URL when compared to the edit response link at the end of the form submittal.  This code is in Google sheets, and is triggered upon a form submit.

```
      var form = FormApp.openById('--form ID here--');
      var responses = form.getResponses();       
      var lastResponse = responses[responses.length - 1];
      var responseURL = lastResponse.getEditResponseUrl();
```

I email this responseURL to the person using the form, but on clicking the link, it produces a 404 error.  If I click on the identical link at the end of the form submittal, it will let me edit the form response.  Would anyone know why there is a 404 error in the first case?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you show what's the difference between those two urls? The one manually created vs the one created from your script

Comment: I see what I did now - I uppercased the body of the text in the email, and it uppercased the form id too.  Then it didn't work anymore because it wasn't the same form id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried replicating your code, but I didn't have that issue with the URL. Here's my version:

```
function getResponseURL() {

  var form = FormApp.openById('id goes here')
  var responses = form.getResponses()
  var lastResponse = responses[responses.length - 1]
  var responseURL = lastResponse.getEditResponseUrl()
  //Logger.log(responseURL)
  
  var emailbody = "Find last form submission link <A HREf=" + responseURL +"> here </A>"
  
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: 'email@example.com',
    subject: 'test',
    htmlBody: emailbody})


}
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Maybe it's something to do with my company's VPN or something.   I will approach it from that end.  Thanks.